# Convert simple Object from C# to VB

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I need to convert this object in C# to VB.NET, but it give me error

```
var data = new
        {
            type = "x large", 
            format = "spcial", 

            queryParameters = new
            {
                dateFrom = "25/10/2022",
                dateTo = "02/11/2025",
                receiverSenderId = 224, 
                receiverSenderType = "Manager", 
                branchNumber = 19,
                statuses = "active",
                productsInternalCodes = "3442342",
                documentTypeNames = "any"
            }
        };
```

I tried this code but it give error because it is in multiline,
If all in one line no error

```
Dim data = New With {Key
.type = "x large", Key
.format = "spcial", Key
.queryParameters = New With {Key
    .dateFrom = "25/10/2022", Key
    .dateTo = "02/11/2025", Key
    .receiverSenderId = 224, Key
    .receiverSenderType = "Manager", Key
    .branchNumber = 19, Key
    .statuses = "active", Key
    .productsInternalCodes = "3442342", Key
    .documentTypeNames = "any"
  }
}
```

Comment: So... use one line? Or use the underscore character?

Comment: Put the dot at the end of the line (after `Key`) instead of at the beginning of the next line. Alternatively, you can just get rid of `Key`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3142254/8967612) for more about the difference.

Comment: `Dim data = New With {Key .type = "x large",` (next line) `Key .format = "spcial",` etc.